# Aux In line won't work for my Yamaha DGX-660

Tags: digital-piano

Title says most of the important stuff. I have a DGX-660 that I'm trying to connect to a loop pedal. I've connected the pedal and tested the output directly from the pedal, and I can hear stuff if I directly plug in my headphones to the pedal so I know the issue isn't with the output.

The problem comes when I try to reroute the audio from the pedal back into the piano. I understand this setup is already less than ideal how I've described it, but it would in theory give me a way to loop using the speakers of the keyboard. Plugging anything into the "Aux In" port in the piano has yet to yield any sound.

I've plugged in both a phone and a TV into the Aux In port to see if there's a way I can get the piano to output anything through the speakers, but it isn't giving me anything.

My main concern is that the Aux In port is broken physically, which would be unfortunate because I don't imagine that's something I'll be able to fix at home (or maybe at all.) I just wanted to see if I could get a second set of eyes to make sure I'm not missing anything obvious.

I've tested the aux cords, the 1/4 adapters and everything to ensure the issue isn't with those components as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you followed the manual and adjusted the AUX-IN volume? From the manual: "You can adjust the volume of the sound input via the AUX IN
jack from the external audio device. To do this, press the
[FUNCTION] button then use the CATEGORY buttons to select
“AUX IN Level,” then adjust the value by using the dial."

Comment: Yeah I saw that in the manual and thought the same thing. the Aux In volume is default at 100, so it should play regardless, but I also cranked it to 127 to see if that would help - no go. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: What kind of cable are you using? 3 rings or 2 rings? Also, from the man: "Do not route the output from the PHONES/OUTPUT jack to
the AUX IN jack. If you make this connection, the signal
input at the AUX IN jack is output from the PHONES/OUT-
PUT jack. These connections could result in a feedback
loop that will make normal performance impossible, and
may even damage both pieces of equipment." You have the looper in between but still…

Comment: If the piano sends the signal coming in to the aux input to the output, then you're going to get an electrical feedback loop if you connect the output to the input. Hopefully you didn't cause any damage when attempting to do that.

Comment: Haha it'd make sense if I inadvertently broke it by doing that... Should have considered that! I'm using 2 ring aux cables. Yeah the looper is between but it may not have helped. Who knows... In any case, a direct plug from my phone or anything else won't work either, so I'm thinking it's probably just a hardware thing.